# nutzen/nützen, tauschen/täuschen, wagen/wägen, etc

Tags: etymology, morphology

What is the name given to verb pairs such as the ones in the thread's title, characterized by coupled vowel→umlauted vowel and meaning shifts?

Comment: What is a "coupled vowel"? Am I parsing this ckrrectly? Please presebt your research on Umlautung because as far as I know (from quite dated literature) the process is not entirely understood. The fact that *wägen* is spelled as such seems to be irrelevent as much as the difference between sg. *Wagen* and pl. *Waagen* (car, respectively scales) as orthographic convention with subsequent spelling pronounciation.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find any specific description related by vowels.
I would assume [Wortfamilie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortfamilie) would be the nearest description, since all pairs of common ancestors.
[Tausch(en)](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tausch)  [nutzen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nutzen)  [wagen](http://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/wagen)

Answer (score 1):

The only name that comes to my mind is cognates, which are words that share the same etymological origin. Two cognates in the same language are also called doublets.

Comment: Wörter die ähnlich geschrieben werden haben aber nicht immer die gleiche Wurzel. Stimmt das überhaupt für die Beispiele?

Comment: @userunknown "Nutzen und nützen" sind genau genommen ein und dasselbe Wort, wobei letzteres nur als Verb im Sinne von "Das nützt mir nichts" verwendet wird. - "Tauschen und täuschen" haben die selbe Wurzel. - "wagen und wägen" letzten Endes auch. *Wägen* stammt sowieso von *wiegen* ab, *wagen* hat in der Tat seine Herleitung aber auch von der *Waage*.

Comment: I don't think, nutzen and nützen are the same, as the former is used in the meaning of "to use" and "to be of value/to be beneficial", whereas the second doesn't have the "to use" meaning.